# SQL Server - CAST AND DIVIDE

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

```
DECLARE @table table(XYZ VARCHAR(8) , id int)

INSERT INTO @table
SELECT '4000', 1
UNION ALL
SELECT '3.123', 2
UNION ALL
SELECT '7.0', 3
UNION ALL
SELECT '80000', 4
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 5
```

Query:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN PATINDEX('^[0-9]{1,5}[\.][0-9]{1,3}$', XYZ) = 0 THEN XYZ
         WHEN PATINDEX('^[0-9]{1,8}$',XYZ) = 0 THEN CAST(XYZ AS decimal(18,3))/1000
         ELSE NULL 
       END
  FROM @table
```

This part - `CAST(XYZ AS decimal(18,3))/1000` doesn't divide the value.

It gives me more number of zeros after decimal instead of dividing it. (I even enclosed that in brackets and tried but same result).

```
Ex:2000/1000 = 2000.000000
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Are patindex expression parameters correct?

```
Expected result:
4.000
3.123
7.000
80.000
```

Do let me know if PATINDEX is not correct method to use?
I'm trying to check if it is already decimal with 3 decimal points else i want to divide by 1000.

Comment: Hi I have something almost working that avoids PATINDEX. What are the rules for diving by 1000? If XYZ includes a decimal point leave as is, if it doesnt /1000 ?

Comment: PATINDEX (Transact-SQL) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx Returns the starting position of the first occurrence of a pattern in a specified expression, or zeros if the pattern is not found, on all valid text and character data types.

Comment: @CResults - It should always be in decimal but sometimes we get bad data 4.000 as 4000 or 2.310 as 2310. So what i'm trying to do is check if it is not in xx.xxx convert it into decimal format.
Yes if it inculdes point leave it

Comment: @rs I think I have what you're after below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
DECLARE @table table(XYZ VARCHAR(8) , id int)

INSERT INTO @table
SELECT '4000', 1
UNION ALL
SELECT '3.123', 2
UNION ALL
SELECT '7.0', 3
UNION ALL
SELECT '80000', 4
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 5
UNION ALL
SELECT 'WTF',6

SELECT CASE 
     WHEN ISNUMERIC(XYZ) = 0 THEN NULL
     WHEN CHARINDEX('.',XYZ,0) < LEN(XYZ)-2 AND CHARINDEX('.',XYZ,0) > 0 THEN XYZ
     WHEN ISNUMERIC(XYZ) >0  then  convert(decimal(18,3),xyz) / 1000.000
     ELSE NULL
END
  FROM @table
```

Output

```
4.00000000000
3.12300000000
0.00700000000
80.00000000000
NULL
NULL
```

Edit - to keep to 3 decimal places in output do this

```
SELECT convert(decimal(8,3),CASE 
     WHEN ISNUMERIC(XYZ) = 0 THEN NULL
     WHEN CHARINDEX('.',XYZ,0) < LEN(XYZ)-2 AND CHARINDEX('.',XYZ,0) > 0 THEN XYZ
     WHEN ISNUMERIC(XYZ) >0  then  convert(decimal(18,3),xyz) / 1000.000
     ELSE NULL
END)
  FROM @table
```

Note the (8,3) defines this, total precision 8 digits, 3 after the point.

You may wish to convert back to varchar(8) too

Comment: perfect thanks this is what i was looking for, But why does it pads extra 8 0's at the end?

Comment: see my edit. I've kept precision to 8 to suit your original varchar

Comment: yes thanks,  I'm confused about what is causing it to pad so many zeros.

Answer (score 1):

try this, convert the entire CASE to decimal(18,3):

```
DECLARE @table table(XYZ VARCHAR(8) , id int)

INSERT INTO @table
SELECT '4000', 1
UNION ALL
SELECT '3.123', 2
UNION ALL
SELECT '7.0', 3
UNION ALL
SELECT '80000', 4
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 5


SELECT CONVERT(decimal(18,3),CASE --nothing changes within the CASE
                                 WHEN PATINDEX('^[0-9]{1,5}[\.][0-9]{1,3}$', XYZ) = 0 THEN XYZ
                                 WHEN PATINDEX('^[0-9]{1,8}$',XYZ) = 0 THEN CAST(XYZ AS decimal(18,3))/1000
                                 ELSE NULL 
                             END
              )
FROM @table
```

OUTPUT:

```
---------------------------------------
4000.000
3.123
7.000
80000.000
NULL

(5 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: not working. I guess PATINDEX is not doing what i was expecting it to do

Comment: if we are dividing by 1000 , 4000.000 = 4.000?

Comment: no it isn't, all rows in the example get processed via the first `WHEN` none by the second `WHEN` and the null row by the `ELSE`.  What are you trying to do with the `PATINDEX`?

Comment: yes i realized that, check my updated question, I'm trying to match using regex

Answer (score 0):

Dividing by 1000 will give you more zeros after the decimal

```
5.3 / 1000 = .0053
```

Comment: nope, the PATINDEX he is using prevents values with a decimal point from being divided by 1000

Comment: lol my question is confusing will correct it, 2000/1000 = 2000.000000 is what I'm getting

Answer (score 0):

```
select xyz, ((case when charindex('.', xyz) > 0 then cast(xyz AS decimal(18,3))*1000
                   else cast(xyz AS decimal(18,3)) end))/1000
from #table
```

Comment: you are close but we don't need that * 1000 extra there :)

Comment: yeah you do or you end up with 4.00000000
0.00312300
0.00700000
80.00000000
NULL